# Aligning Multiple Elements to Bottom of Parent

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to align multiple input boxes to the bottom of the parent div. For example:

```css
    .inner-container {
        margin-right: 10px;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="outer-container">
        <div class="inner-container">
            <label>Test</label><br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="something here" />
        </div>
        <div class="inner-container">
            <label>Test</label><br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="something here" />
        </div>
        <div class="inner-container">
            <input type="text" placeholder="something here" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Notice how the last input box is not aligned with the other input boxes. I am trying to get this box to vertically align with the others.

I am also trying to get this to also work on IE11 (Outdated I know) while also working on modern browsers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trivial solution is to add a `br` if you don't want complex CSS and to be sure it works for the *dead* IE:

```css
.inner-container {
        margin-right: 10px;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
        <div class="inner-container">
            <label>Test</label><br >
            <input type="text" placeholder="something here" >
        </div>
        <div class="inner-container">
            <label>Test</label><br >
            <input type="text" placeholder="something here" >
        </div>
        <div class="inner-container">
             <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="something here" >
        </div>
    </div>
```

Or replace float with `inline-block` and keep the default `vertical-align`:

```css
.inner-container {
        margin-right: 10px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
        <div class="inner-container">
            <label>Test</label><br >
            <input type="text" placeholder="something here" >
        </div>
        <div class="inner-container">
            <label>Test</label><br >
            <input type="text" placeholder="something here" >
        </div>
        <div class="inner-container">
            <input type="text" placeholder="something here" >
        </div>
    </div>
```